# React useEffect and useState interaction

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React and Material UI to create a table (XGrid) with some buttons. When you click the row, it should set the row id using `useState`. When you click the delete button, it should delete the row. It seems that the delete click handler is not using the value from use state. This is either some kind of closure thing or some kind of React thing.

```
const MyTableThing: React.FC = (props) => 
{
  const { data } = props;
  const [filename, setFilename] = React.useState<string>("")
  const [columns, setColumns] = React.useState<GridColDef[]>([])

  const handleDelete = () =>
  {
    someFunctionThatDeletes(filename); // filename is always ""
    setFilename(""); // Does not do anything.. !
  }

  React.useEffect(() =>
  {
    if (data)
    {
      let columns: GridColumns = data.columns;
      columns.forEach((column: GridColDef) =>
      {
        if (column.field === "delete")
        {
          column.renderCell = (cellParams: GridCellParams) =>
          {
            return <Button onClick={handleDelete}>Delete</Button>
          }
        }
      })

      setColumns(columns)
    }
  }, [data?.files])

  // Called when a row is clicked
  const handleRowSelected = (param: GridRowSelectedParams) =>
  {
    console.log(`set selected row to ${param.data.id}`) // This works every time
    setFilename(param.data.id)
  }
}
```

Comment: I have a feeling it has to do with the fact that `column.renderCell` is a function that returns a value, which contains `handleDelete` - the handleDelete within that function is inside a closure, so the values being used within `handleDelete` there might be stale.  What happens if you simply return the Button, instead of the `column.renderCell`?

Comment: Is this all of the code for the component?  Just curious why you're not returning/rendering JSX in this example and instead doing some of that processing in an effect hook.

Comment: I don't know man, just trying to follow what everyone else in the project is doing. They always put this into a useEffect. I tried outside of the useEffect but ran into some kind of infinite loop issue.

Comment: The simple fix is to add `handleDelete` to the dependencies of your useEffect hook.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this behavior is that React does not process setState action synchronously. It is stacked up with other state changes and then executed. React does this to improve performance of the application. Read following link for more details on this.
https://linguinecode.com/post/why-react-setstate-usestate-does-not-update-immediately

you can disable your deleteRow button till the filename variable is updated. you can use useEffect or setState with callback function.

```
useEffect(() => {
        //Enable your delete row button, fired when filename is updated
        }, filename)
```

OR

```
this.setFilename(newFilename, () => {
  // ... enable delete button
});
```

Let me know if this helps! Please mark it as answer if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem I see here is that you are rendering JSX in a useEffect hook, and then saving the output JSX into columns state. I assume you are then returning that state JSX from this functional component. That is a very bizarre way of doing things, and I would not recommend that.

However, this explains the problem. The JSX being saved in state has a stale version of the `handleDelete` function, so that when `handleDelete` is called, it does not have the current value of `filename`.

Instead of using the useEffect hook and columns state, simply do that work in your return statement. Or assign the work to a variable and then render the variable. Or better yet, use a useMemo hook.

Notice that we add handleDelete to the useMemo dependencies. That way, it will re-render every time handleDelete changes. Which currently changes every render. So lets fix that by adding useCallback to handleDelete.

```js
const MyTableThing: React.FC = (props) => {
  const { data } = props;
  const [filename, setFilename] = React.useState<string>('');

  const handleDelete = React.useCallback(() => {
    someFunctionThatDeletes(filename); // filename is always ""
    setFilename(''); // Does not do anything.. !
  }, [filename]);

  const columns = React.useMemo(() => {
    if (!data) {
      return null;
    }

    let columns: GridColumns = data.columns;
    columns.forEach((column: GridColDef) => {
      if (column.field === 'delete') {
        column.renderCell = (cellParams: GridCellParams) => {
          return <Button onClick={handleDelete}>Delete</Button>;
        };
      }
    });
    return columns;
  }, [data?.files, handleDelete]);

  // Called when a row is clicked
  const handleRowSelected = (param: GridRowSelectedParams) => {
    console.log(`set selected row to ${param.data.id}`); // This works every time
    setFilename(param.data.id);
  };

  return columns;
};
```

Comment: It looks good, but no luck with this. When I click the row, I do see it updating the `filename` state. But when I click delete, it is still calling delete with a blank filename.. :S